# Есть ли библиотека Node.js для управления комплектующими компьютера?

Tags: node.js, поиск-библиотек

Есть ли такая библиотека для Node.js, с помощью которой я бы мог управлять комплектующими компьютера, заставить кулер/видеокарту компьютера работать на полную? Не выполняя при этом никакого рендера. Просто, скажем, консольное приложение. Ввёл команду `cooler max` и компьютер зашумел. Ввёл `cooler off` и компьютер стал безшумным.

Comment: Ввёл `cooler off` и сгорел компьютер.

Comment: вот прям под ноду нету, это слишком низкоуровневые вещи, как вариант это использовать какую-то библиотеку на C++ / Rust, компилировать в WASM, далее инициализировать WASM модуль через API V8 и использовать в ноде

Comment: @overthesanity Почти все подобные модули под ноду - это обёртка, которая просто запускает скомпилированную программу. Даже банальный нотификатор и то так делает.

Comment: @Aid, я бы не назвал это оберткой, эти модули не делают ничего сверхъестественного, это просто посредники, возьмем банальный нотификатор (`node-notifier`) например, написан на чистом js, и в зависимости от ОС - обращается с командной строки (через `child_process`) к какой-то либе (`libnotify` в линуксе например)